# Нейронная сеть распознавания паттернов. Класс "неизвестного"

Tags: нейронные-сети, matlab, распознавание-образов

Я создал нейронную сеть для распознавания паттернов (профилей пользователей) на основе некоторых параметров (сигмоида в скрытом слое, softmax в выходном слое, рисунок ниже). Но я столкнулся с проблемой: когда я предоставляю нейросети, обученной на нескольких паттернах (параметрах профиля), какой-то новый паттерн (параметры профиля), нейросеть присваивает его известным ей классам. Какие существуют способы добавления дополнительного паттерна, с которым нейронная сеть будет соотносить те профили, которые не соответствуют никаким другим известным ей реальным шаблонам (реальным профилям)?

[Структура нейросети](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Om5.png)

Я пытался создать случайный набор входных данных (в пределах примерного диапазона значений параметров профиля), но это не сработало.

Comment: Ну, например, можно делать one vs all или как это правильно называется. То есть делаете нейросеть, которая детектирует строго один класс, а не все. И так для каждого класса. Потом показываете образец всем этим нейросетям и смотрите, есть ли хоть у одной из них уверенность больше какого-то порога. Если нет, то это какой-то новый образец. Если есть, то у какой больше всех уверенность, такой это и образец. Но это тоже не факт что сработает. По-хорошему нужно смотреть, чем отличается этот новый образец от тех, что уже есть и почему у вас он определяется как один из старых. Случаи разные бывают.